# Stuck at Asus Logo

Tags: linux, hard-drive, laptop, bios

My laptop model is Asus p2540uv. It has Fedora 29 as my primary OS alongside with Linux Mint and Windows 10. I was using Fedora(I wasn't upgrading system at that moment) and suddenly the screen becomes black. After forcing shutdown and powering up laptop, it was stuck at Asus logo screen. Couldn't even get into BIOS menu. Pressed F10, F9 etc various key, nothing worked. Tried to boot from bootable USB(Linux Mint), but couldn't get past of Logo screen. Then I removed hard drive, ram, battery and put all back; it didn't solve the problem. I again removed hard drive and started the computer without it; this time it worked, I was able to get into BIOS menu and boot into Linux Mint from USB.

Seems like the problem was with the hard drive. Whenever I attached it, the computer was stuck at Asus Logo screen. I repeated hard drive remove-attach thing 2/3 times, suddenly it worked and I was able to boot from hard drive.

I checked Fedora, seems it is fine, nothing is wrong with it.

Can anyone tell me what the problem really was? And how can I prevent this from happening at future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a power-up problem of the hard drive (hd). You can power the pins and check if it starts up?

My advise is to check the pins on the hd and the laptop side. This could be a potential repair. The other is replacement of the hd (but then you need to think of how to transfer data from your broken hd).

Sometimes a failing device gives a POST that presents a blocking point to boot the computer. But also the mainboard can detect failing devices that may keep it from starting up. For example, if some power connections are cut short or basic communication bus isn't accessible.

Hope my advice can help you!